# Uniform random distribution in java

Tags: java, math

i'm generating Random values with range of 5.0 - 9.0, **are the numbers generated still uniformly distributed theoretically** ??

and how to implement the histogram, i mean what  values we need to implement the histogram  ??

```
import java.util.Random;

public class GenerateNumber {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            double randomDou = randomGenerator.nextDouble() * (9 - 5 + 1) + 5;
            System.out.println(randomDou);
        }
    }
}
```

- i'm zero on math .., pls help me

Comment: i mean, if we scale the generated values, is it still uniform distribution ??

Comment: `(9 - 5 + 1)` Why do you do this like that? Why don't you just write 5?

Comment: min =5 , max = 9 , the formula i find on google is randomGenerator.nextDouble() *(max-min+1)-min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the righ path- scaling the numbers linearly is correct.

To test your logic, plug in 0.0 and 1.0 as values from nextDouble()

```
0.0 * (9 - 5 + 1) + 5 = 5, o.k.
1.0 * (9 - 5 + 1) + 5 = 10, not o.k.
```

This is a basic way to test your math.

Comment: sir i still dont understand , so why u assume  <b>1.0 * (9 - 5 + 1) + 5 = 10</b> wrong ??

Comment: @febri23 `1.0` is the largest value that `nextDouble()` could return. In that situation, your equation would produce the result `10`. This is wrong - you want the range to finish at `9`.

Comment: thx sir, so when we scale the numbers the distribution still remains uniform??, so how i draw the histogram what i need on x-axis n y-axis, i know that y-axis represents frequency but what on x-axis ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Littile math bug

There is a little bug in the code. You want to have randomly generated numbers between 5.0 to 9.0 but the code you post will give you numbers between 5. and 10.0. So the code should be changed a little bit in the following way:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            double randomDou = randomGenerator.nextDouble() * (9 - 5) + 5;
            System.out.println(randomDou);
        }
    }
}
```

It should be `(9 - 5)` instead of `(9 - 5 + 1)` because the later one will give you a range from 5.0 (not included) to 10.0 (included).

#### Uniformity

Yes, the number will uniformally distributed in the way you did. The `java.util.random` generates uniformally distributed numbers [1]. Intuitively, `aχ(x) + b`**(1)** where a and b are both constants is also uniformally distributed if and only if χ(x) is uniformally distributed.

Back to the question, `randomGenerator.nextDouble() * (9 - 5) + 5` is in the form of the **Eq.(1)** where

- `(9 - 5)` -> a
- `randomGenerator.nextDouble()` -> χ(x)
- `5` -> b

So yes it is  uniformally distributed.

Sorry for the second question about the histrogram because it is not clear and confusing me.

Ref links: [1]:[https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/summaries/60mathsum.html](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ediam/java/online/notes-java/summaries/60mathsum.html)